# how to allow files starting with period and no extension in windows 2003 server?

Tags: mercurial, windows-server-2003, hgignore

How can I create this file in a directory in windows 2003 SP2:

```
.hgignore
```

I get error: You must type a file name.

Comment: This is not related to software development? How to make an ignore file on windows server for mercurial? What is it related to, then, masonry and plumbing?

Comment: Relevant:  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/  I mean, a more helpful way to deal with this issue would have been to migrate the question to Super User.  Anyway, I found the question and answer useful, so I gave them upvotes.

Comment: Related post on the desired forum - [Create/rename a file/folder that begins with a dot in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/64471/374397)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's a "feature" of Windows Explorer. Try to create your files from a command line (or from a batch/program you wrote) and it should work fine. Try this from a dos prompt:

```
echo Hello there! > .hgignore
```

Comment: You CAN. Just type another dot at the end. Type the name as 
`.hgignore.`

Comment: That works, but only on Vista or later.

Comment: The MSWindows command line interface is not a "DOS prompt" in NT-based OS versions.

Comment: @ecm I will never not ridicule the tacked-on, inferior and clunky DOS prompt of Windows by not calling it a DOS prompt.  (:-P)

Answer (score 5):

By the way Raymond Chen had a blog post about this topic a while back:

[Why doesn't Explorer let you create a file whose name begins with a dot?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080414-00/?p=22763) (archive.org link with comments: https://web.archive.org/web/20100305064616/http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/04/14/8389268.aspx)

In which he mentions

> You can do it from the command line or
> use your favorite file management
> tool.

Comment: 'or use your favorite file management tool' # Useful, I thought Explorer was a 'file management tool'