# How do I name the .bowerrc file?

Tags: bower, mean-stack

[This MEAN-stack tutorial](http://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/introduction-to-the-mean-stack-part-one-setting-up-your-tools/) describes using Bower to install AngularJS in your public folder.  One of the steps describes creating a file called ".bowerrc" in your test-app folder.  However, Windows won't let you create a file without a name.  How do I accomplish this on a Windows system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004633/how-to-manually-create-a-file-with-a-dot-prefix-in-windows-for-example-htacce

Answer (score 52, accepted):

on the command line (make sure to cd into your working directory), issue this command:

```
touch .bowerrc
```

This will also work for other files common to webdev like `.htaccess` and `.gitignore`

Note:  If you haven't installed git bash for windows, you may not have support for the `touch` command.  In that case (as mentioned in one of the comments here), the easiest way to accomplish this is via the cli with:

```
echo "" > .bowerrc
```

Comment: @JeffHubbard - I had already installed the Git Bash tool described in that tutorial, so I was able to use 'touch'.

Comment: Regarding touch ... there's another question here on SO describing a simple (MSDN-documented!) way to simulate touch with Windows. Look for `copy /b filename.ext +,,` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, `echo "" > .bowerrc` from cmd also works for me (Windows 8).

Comment: @JeffHubbard, that's a good point, but his tutorial installed the git module, so it was relevant here. If you're using bower, chances are great your cli has support for `touch`

Answer (score 31):

To create a file that starts with a "." in Windows, you just need to add a trailing ".".

So, simply name your file ".bowerrc." instead of ".bowerrc".

See https://superuser.com/questions/64471/create-rename-a-file-folder-that-begins-with-a-dot-in-windows for more information and more detailed solution if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it doesn't depends on cmd or any other tools apart from explorer

Answer (score 6):

Another way to accomplish this is through Notepad++.

- Create the file in Notepad++
- Set the encoding to "Encoding in ANSI" (click "Encoding" in the menu bar)
- Save the file as .bowerrc (change the "Save as type:" to *.* which is one list item up from *.txt)

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 5):

Simply rename the file you created:

```
C:\project> ren bowerrc .bowerrc
```