# How can I specify with broccolijs the destination folder of the main bower files?

Tags: bower, broccolijs

Hi I am trying to setup broccoli but if I want my file in bower_components to go on a specific folder let's say public/vendor how do i do it ?
I get the main bower files and then merge with the rest of my files

```
var findBowerTrees = require('broccoli-bower');
var sourceTrees = [appCss, appJs];
sourceTrees = sourceTrees.concat(findBowerTrees());
module.exports = mergeTrees(sourceTrees, {overwrite: true});
```

then I run broccoli build public

```
structure is
--js
--css
--bower_components
in public shoud result
--public
  --js
  --css
  --vendor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `.bowerrc` file at root of your project.

```
{
  "directory": "public/vendor/"
}
```

You can find more configuration parameters [here](http://bower.io/docs/config/)

**NOTE:** to create `.bowerrc` file on windows see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202202/how-do-i-name-the-bowerrc-file) SO question.