# creating htaccess file in wamp server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

I am trying to create .htaccess file inside wamp/www/myDirectory.
But i am not able to create, it says `'you must type file name'`

I have enabled the mod-rewrite also. Now i want to check URL hiding,but i am not able to create .htaccess.

I have created .htaccess file and written code like  this

```
# Avoid redirect loop
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^purchase(.*)$ $1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/purchase/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ purchase/$1 [L,QSA]
```

How can i do this. Please suggest

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manually create a file with a . dot prefix in windows for example .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004633/how-to-manually-create-a-file-with-a-dot-prefix-in-windows-for-example-htacce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried creating the file via Notepad?

Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004695/460053

Comment: Thanks Peter. It worked for me. Can you please suggest me is my above code is write or not? basically i am trying to hide purchase folder name from url

Comment: I no longer use apache, so am unable to verify your code. Give it a try, and see what happens?

Answer (score -1):

In windows, just go to the folder using cmd and type the following command 
`DIR>.htaccess`.

This command will create a `.htaccess` file and will dump some data in it.