# PHP Front Controller and .htaccess with XAMPP and Windows

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to get a simple front controller for routing set up. This is the front-controller.php file I have:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/help') {
    include 'help.php';
}
```

this is a .htaccess file I have in the folder with my index.php (which is under htdocs/wad)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . /front-controller.php [L]
```

In `httpd.conf` I changed all instances of the `AllowOverride None` line to `AllowOverride All` and I uncommented the `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` line.

I am getting Error 404 if I try to go to localhost/wad/help and even localhost/wad: http://puu.sh/cE6WT/2e4c645555.png

The help.php file exists. I want to be able to browse to localhost/wad/help and have it load (in the same page, not redirect to it). Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: I am open a filezilla, create a .htacess on the remote server, and download to my localhost. But there are several ways to create a .htaccess on windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004633/how-to-manually-create-a-file-with-a-dot-prefix-in-windows-for-example-htacce

Comment: Thank you! Now the .htaccess file is definitely being used but I can no longer access any page, I get Object not found even on localhost/wad/

Comment: edit your question, and show us your whole .htaccess file content.

Comment: edited - that is the whole file content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, there is a much more better way, if you are use your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /front-controller.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And then in your `front-controller.php` you can use the `$_GET["action"]` parse it, and route where you want.