# PHP subfolder used as home directory

Tags: php

I am coding a website with php, html, css and a few javascript.
I am on localhost, more exactly LAMP server, and for me to access this "website" the url on the browser is `http://localhost/website`.

What I want is to have an subfolder that has a `index.php`. So I had made an `index.php` on the main folder that includes the `subfolder/index.php` and everything works great.

Now I want to create an about page on the subfolder (`subfolder/about.php`). However the url should be `localhost/website/about.php` and this doesn't work.

How can I have a subfolder like it was the main folder to display?

trying to simplify the question:

```
website/
    subfolder/
        index.php
        about.php
        products.php
        etc.php
    index.php
```

imaging that this above is the files directory, probably its possible to understand.

so the link should be website/about.php   and not website/subfolder/about.php
basically what I need is that the subfolder acts like it was the root folder of the website.

Comment: You got a response. maybe error etc.? What means doesn't work?

Comment: `website/about.php >>> <?php include 'website/subfolder/about.php';`? It sounds like you really want a simple front controller (e.g. `website/index.php` acts as the locator of the request's context, like `website/index.php?page=about`).

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are asking for. Is it possible you are looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: I would like the subfolder act like it was the main domain.  any website/anypage.php should work like that and not  webset/subfolder/anypage.php

Comment: It's a goog idea to build your web defining a base path and a base URI.

Comment: "this doesn't work" - what does that mean? Please share more details

Comment: basically all I want is to code files in the subfolder  and display them in the url  website/anyfile.php   and not website/subfolder/anyfile.php

Comment: Rather than duplicating your efforts, or writing a front controller, or using other rewrite hacks:  I personally find it's just easier to redefine your document root.  If you are on a *nix machine, you could try a symlink.  Instead of a folder for your document root, you can link there.  Or the subfolder etc.  I tend to do `/var/www -> /path/to/project/www` for a simple development environment switch.

Comment: If you have an asset included within your `about.php`, like an image or javascript, note that your links may break by this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Simple front contoller:

**website/index.php**

```
<?php

switch ($_GET['page'] ?: 'index')
{
    case 'about':
        require 'website/subfolder/about.php';
    break;
    case 'products':
        require 'website/subfolder/products.php';
    break;
    default: // index
        require 'website/subfolder/index.php';
}
```

Then setup a front controller rewrite using an `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26755631/451969

Now urls like these should indirect to your `website/index.php` front controller as a `page` GET variable:

```
website             # index
website/about       # about page
website/products    # products listing
```

Comment: I am using a LAMP server. Should this .htaccess be in the website/  directory

Comment: @tiagocalado I think so; you might have to tweak it a little. For instance, you might need to remove the `/website` part if it's in the website folder. I don't mess with `RewriteRule` very often...

Comment: This seems to be a good solution, redirect any url to the index.php and from there make the distribution, I can work with this. however in my localhost It seems the .htaccess is not being apply, maybe this is in my system, I am using a LAMP configuration?

Comment: @tiagocalado Also, I'd recommend putting those PHP files out of the web path so they can't be accessed directly with http. Somewhere below the web root. An alternative is to add some code to force redirect if that doesn't happen (e.g. test if a constant you define in `website/index.php` is set and if not, redirect to it's pure route).

Comment: @tiagocalado You should be able to use `.htaccess` if you have Apache. Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience debugging Apache scripts.

Comment: thanks for the info, this makes sense to me, I believe its just on my system that probably isnt working for some reason, must figure it this out.

Comment: @tiagocalado I won't be able to right away, but I'll see if I can create a repo that works as described.

Answer (score 0):

just use this code

```
<?php
  $uri = urldecode(
 parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 
 PHP_URL_PATH)
 );

 if ($uri !== '/' && 
 file_exists(__DIR__.'/subfolder'.$uri)) {
 return false;
 }

 require_once 
  __DIR__.'/subfolder/index.php';
```

Comment: it works for the index.php subfolder, then I have there <a href="./about.php">about</a> , this opens website/about.php with 404 error code, and I have the about.php but in the subfolder

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does it include `about.php`  from the subfolder? Also, how do you ensure that this does not create security issues where you could include any file from the system?

Comment: This is an incomplete answer.  You check that a file exists, but do nothing with it.

Comment: @tiagocalado you can easily create functions or routes to go to a particular page for example in place of index.php just get the url and store its value in a vairable then use it in place of index.php simple