# Installing theano on Windows 7 x64 (cannot import name gof)

Tags: python, windows, installation, theano

I am trying to install Theano on my Windows 7 x64 machine.  I have followed about 5 different tutorials trying to get it installed properly.  Some of them are in these links:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html

https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/forums/t/13973/a-few-tips-to-install-theano-on-windows-64-bits

On the Kaggle site I tried the Anaconda and WinPython recommendations...  I've tried using Python 2.7 and 3.5... it doesn't seem to matter what I do; I keep getting the following error(s) when I run

```
import theano
```

in my python environment:

```
...
^~~~~;mingw-w64/x86_64-6.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/include/c++/cmath:1133:11: error: '::hypot' has not been declared\mod.cpp:1:/c++/math.h:36:0,
```

That's what I get the first time I try to import theano.  If I try a second time in the same session I get

```
...
from theano import config, gof

ImportError: cannot import name gof
```

I found [this other question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444173/error-importing-theano-cannot-import-name-gof) that makes it seem that I have an old version of Theano installed causing the problem.  I already ran

```
pip uninstall theano
```

and it is no longer installed.  Is there another way to uninstall it that I'm missing?  Or do I have another issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my own problem here.  If anyone else out that encounters this, I did the following to resolve it

1. Remove every version of Theano you can find; `pip uninstall theano`, `conda remove theano`, and search your file system for Theano files that might be lingering around
2. I also had a couple of versions of mingw on my machine.  Remove all of those as well; I started with the standard window uninstall.  I was also able to find another installation squirreled away in my file system that had a separate uninstall package that I ran.
3. Follow the instructions on the 2nd post of [this link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/forums/t/13973/a-few-tips-to-install-theano-on-windows-64-bits) EXACTLY

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem: ImportError: cannot import name gof
for Windows 10 64 bit, Python 2.7. I solved by updating conda several times to make sure there are not more updates. I run:

1. conda update conda
2. conda update --all

After that in the Python environment of the Anaconda prompt shell,

1. import theano