# module 'theano' has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: python, keras, theano

I just try to import the packages first on Jupyter Notebook

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

but I got this error 
AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'compile'

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41191592/9215780).

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem by install theano from conda source-forge