# Why does .gitignore use an empty basename?

Tags: git, naming-conventions, filenames, gitignore

Any time I see a [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file in a Git repository, I can't help but notice that, aside from the file extension, the filename is completely empty. Because of this, I've often seen new programmers run into the "[*You must enter a filename*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245658/you-must-type-a-file-name-error-thrown-when-i-create-a-gitignore-file-on-win)" error on Windows when learning Git for the first time.

Other standard files such as `README.md` include basenames, so it seems odd to exclude the name for `.gitignore`.

Is there a reason `.gitignore`'s basename is always empty? Would the file still work properly if it were given a filename like `project-name.gitignore`?

Comment: filenames with `.` in front are a convention for "hidden" files on unix. `.gitignore` can be viewed like a hidden file with no extension. Windows doesn't approve of it much though.

Comment: I think just to hide the file from normal user, So that user does not change it by mistake.

Comment: See [What are dot-files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94780/what-are-dot-files) on Ask Ubuntu for more examples.

Comment: I view `.gitignore` as a file name with no extension. If it had an extension, it would be, e.g., `.gitignore.txt`. But what is the extension of a file named `a.b.c.d.e`?  Is it `d.e`, or `b.c.d.e`?  It's clearly not `.e`: that would be silly! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by others in the comments, a dot in front of a filename implies a hidden file in unix/linux systems.

> Would the file still work properly if it were given a filename like project-name.gitignore?

No, it would not. Git only looks for file named `.gitignore` (plus your global ignore file defined in config).

> Other standard files such as README.md include basenames, so it seems odd to exclude the name for .gitignore.

README.md is not a standard file in Git, it is something that many hosting providers use. Standard git files such as `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` have a consistent naming convention.