# R - here() function, what's a .here file?

Tags: r

I'm struggling to find the answer to this very basic question and to make the here() function work (from the here package). I'd be glad if someone could help me with that.

What's a file .here mentionned in this [github](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here)? And how can I create one ?

I've tried adding a text file called '.here.txt' in my workflow (where I want the here() function to "start") but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you have problems creating the .here look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245658/you-must-type-a-file-name-error-thrown-when-i-create-a-gitignore-file-on-win

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *need* a here file. That's one of the possibilities though. But if you want to use that route then make a file called `.here`

Not `.here.txt` or `here.txt` or any other variant you can think of. Literally just `.here`

Comment: interesting whether `.here` file is respected when the `.R` script is called from a cron job via `Rscript`  and when that script refers to another file either another `.R` script or a rmarkdown `.Rmd` script knitted via knitr.

Comment: It's almost three years later and I'm a bit Christmas drunk so maybe this contributes but... What are you even saying?

Comment: How lucky you should look at this; I just created the question explaining what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425366/here-issue-in-r-scripts