# Why is RStudio telling me that my file doesn't exist? I'm looking directly at it

Tags: r

[image: What I'm seeing]

I'm on RStudio, just wanting to read a csv file:

```r
newdata <- read_csv("Nameofdata.csv",
       col_names = TRUE)
```

But it keeps telling me that the file doesn't exist. It does exist. I'm staring DIRECTLY at it, underneath the file path that RStudio insists is wrong. I can open it in another tab, I can open in in excel, it's EXACTLY where RStudio says it's not existing. Please help.

Comment: Are you using an absolute path or a relative path? If your code snippet is right, make sure the file you want to read is in the current working directory. (See eipi10's comment.)

Comment: Run `getwd()` in the console. That's the folder your R session is currently pointing to. Is that the folder where the file is located?

Comment: Please show your full code, i.e the libraries you are loading. read_sav is not from base R. Also, what does getwd() tell you? Does it give you the folder the file is stored in?

Comment: Does `list.files()` return the name of the file?

Comment: Looks like there is an extra space before `.csv`. If the file name has been built from data using `paste` function then it's a common problem (instead use `paste0` or set `sep` to `""` (empty string))

Comment: @Billy34, how can you see that??

Comment: You do need to be comfortable with the concept of file/directory [path](https://swcarpentry.github.io/shell-novice/02-filedir/index.html) - read at least the first 2 sections. Then the two commands `getwd()` and `setwd()` will help. You can practice the some more problematic use cases in R by reading about executing a script from Rstudio or from command-line [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425366/here-issue-in-r-scripts).

Comment: Looking more closely at the image in the OP, it looks like @Billy34 identified the problem!

Answer (score 4):

Looking **very** closely at your screen shot, commenters are suggesting that you have an extra space at the beginning of your file name.

Also, I see that the working directory **appears** to be correct (the error message lists it as `C:/users/mdavi/Desktop/School/Research/Sc`, which appears to match what is listed in the Files pane

A couple of strategies for trouble-shooting file-locating problems:

- use `getwd()` and `list.files()` to confirm your working directory and what files R can see from there (you can read [this introduction](https://swcarpentry.github.io/shell-novice/02-filedir/index.html) to get more background on working directories):
- use `file.choose()` to select a file interactively; it's generally a bad idea to use this in production code, as it will add an interactive step when you usually want to be able to run all of your code start to finish without needing manual steps, but it's quite useful for debugging.

If you wanted R to list files that *approximately* matched your specified filename, you could use

```r
L <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
agrep("myfile.csv", L, value=TRUE)
```

---

You need to set your **working directly** correctly, either via `setwd("~/Desktop/School/Research/SC")` in the R Console (that's what I think I see in your screenshot: `~` stands for your home directory, i.e "Users/Whoever") or via `Session > Set Working Directory > To File Pane` in the RStudio menus.

You can read a [variety of Stack Overflow questions about setting the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%22working+directory%22) for more complete context ... web searching on "R 'working directory'" might help  too.

---