# Unable to create .babelrc file

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to install ReactJS onto my Windows 7 machine, by following this tutorial:
https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-setup-ii

But when I try to create a file called *.babelrc*, I'm unable to create the file. It says that I have to provide a filename.

I've tried several "hacks" I've seen online, but none of them seem to work.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manually create a file with a . dot prefix in windows for example .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004633/how-to-manually-create-a-file-with-a-dot-prefix-in-windows-for-example-htacce)

Comment: you can add your babelrc values in the webpack config file. Are you using webpack for build ?